# expected identifier for type name

Tags: ios, swift

The below code is giving me the error:

> expected identifier for type name

Maybe it could be the reason that I should handle with it with self, because I saw some post. but it didn't work.

What kind of identifier Xcode talks about me?
And how can I fix it?

If I fixed this error, but there are more errors, should I work with a `UITableViewController` rather than a separate `UIViewController` and `UITableViewDelegate`?

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class Home: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,  {  //error here "expected identifier for type name"


    @IBOutlet weak var homepageTableView: UITableView!
    var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
    var imageText = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { ( posts : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                //불러오는데 성공
                for posts in posts! {
                    self.imageFiles.append(posts["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
                    self.imageText.append(posts["imageText"] as! String)
                    println(self.imageFiles.count)
                }

                /**reload the table **/
                self.homepageTableView.reloadData()
                println("reloaded")
            } else {
                println(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageFiles.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView:  UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell

        //text
        cell.previewCommentLabel.text = imageText[indexPath.row]

        //image
        imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ ( imageData : NSData?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

            if imageData != nil {
                //ㅇㅋ
                var image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.previewImage.image = image
            }else {
                println(error)
                //no
            }
        })

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a comma in your class definition that isn't needed (after `UITableViewDelegate`).

Change:

```
class Home: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,  {  //error here "expected identifier for type name"
```

to:

```
class Home: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate  {  //error here "expected identifier for type name"
```

Using a `UITableViewController` instead of a `UIViewController` with `UITableViewDelegate` shouldn't make much difference, as you will still have to implement the same delegate methods.

However, you will have to implement `UITableViewDataSource` in order to populate the table view. `UITableViewDelegate` is for handling selection of rows (etc.) rather than displaying them.

Significantly, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are part of `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: yes that was accurate so much. and can I ask you one more thing?

Comment: let cell : TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell    // I have error in this part about optional value bad instruction.( unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value) could you give me a shot?

Comment: Did you set the reuse identifier for your template cell in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra comma there.

```
class Home: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,  {  //error here "expected identifier for type name"
```

Should be:

```
class Home: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate  {  //error here "expected identifier for type name"
```